# How can I fork a new process using mcfork in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I seem to be unable to fork a new process in RStudio using `mcfork` from `parallel`, though this works in a standard R console on linux / OS X. Is there an alternative workaround to forking a subprocess in RStudio?

For example, consider this function:

```
library(parallel)
f <- function() {
    p <- parallel:::mcfork()
    if (inherits(p, "masterProcess")) {
      cat("I'm a child!")
      parallel:::mcexit()
    }
    cat("I'm the master\n")
}
```

In my standard R console I get the expected output:

> I'm the master 
> > I'm a child!

But in Rstudio, I get:

> I'm the master

Comment: `RStudio` has a number of quirks. You might want to go to their forums to see if/how they support `mcfork` .

Comment: It's specifically a quirk with how stdout/stderr redirection is handled in child processes forked from R within RStudio, but note that this would work if e.g. you were to redirect that output to a file, e.g. `cat("I'm a child!", file = "~/child.txt")`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because R 4+ doesn't even include mcfork anymore, so this will never be answered.

Comment: Happy to close this too.

Comment: @webb Does R version 4 preclude people from using older versions of R or R studio? If not, then it would be improper to close this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is now irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Answer converted from [a comment by Kevin Ushey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314011/how-can-i-fork-a-new-process-using-mcfork-in-rstudio#comment43115664_27314011):</sub>

> It's specifically a quirk with how stdout/stderr redirection is handled in child processes forked from R within RStudio, but note that this would work if e.g. you were to redirect that output to a file, e.g. `cat("I'm a child!", file = "~/child.txt")`
>
> - [Kevin Ushey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1342082/kevin-ushey) Dec 6 '14 at 5:00 AM