# how to track progress in mclapply in R in parallel package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply, mclapply

My question is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984556/is-there-way-to-track-progress-on-a-mclapply). However the question referenced above uses `multicore` package which was replaced by `parallel`. Most of the functions in the response cannot be replicated in the `parallel` package. Is there a way to track progress in `mclapply`. In looking at the `mclapply` documentation, there is a parameter called `mc.silent`, I'm not sure if this would be able to track progress, and if so how and where we can see the log file? I'm running on `ubuntu` linux OS. Please see below for a reproducible example for which I would like to tack progress.

```
require(parallel) 

wait.then.square <- function(xx){
  # Wait for one second
  Sys.sleep(2);
  # Square the argument 
  xx^2 } 

output <- mclapply( 1:10, wait.then.square, mc.cores=4,mc.silent=FALSE)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an update of my [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10993589/271678).

```
library(parallel)

finalResult <- local({
  f <- fifo(tempfile(), open="w+b", blocking=T)
  if (inherits(parallel:::mcfork(), "masterProcess")) {
    # Child
    progress <- 0.0
    while (progress < 1 && !isIncomplete(f)) {
      msg <- readBin(f, "double")
      progress <- progress + as.numeric(msg)
      cat(sprintf("Progress: %.2f%%\n", progress * 100))
    } 
    parallel:::mcexit()
  }
  numJobs <- 100
  result <- mclapply(1:numJobs, function(...) {
    # Do something fancy here... For this example, just sleep
    Sys.sleep(0.05)
    # Send progress update
    writeBin(1/numJobs, f)
    # Some arbitrary result
    sample(1000, 1)
  })
  close(f)
  result
})

cat("Done\n")
```

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to the package `pbmcapply` you can now easily track progress of `mclapply` and `mcmapply` jobs. Just replace `mclapply` by `pbmclapply`:

```
wait.then.square <- function(xx) {
    Sys.sleep(2)
    xx^2 
} 

library(pbmcapply)
output <- pbmclapply(1:10, wait.then.square, mc.cores = 4)
```

...which will display a pretty progress bar.

The author has a nice blog post on the technical details and performance benchmarks [here](https://kevinkuang.net/tracking-progress-in-r-ad97998c359f#.f6038hioc).

Comment: Thank you very much. Do we know if pbmclapply work in windows?

Comment: mclapply generally does not work on Windows. On Windows the pbapply package is an option for tracking progress without parallelization. I don't think it supports parallel apply functions.