# parSapply and progress bar

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply

I am using the function parSapply to run a simulation on the parallel environment. Here is my code:

```
runpar <- function(i) MonteCarloKfun(i=i)

# Detect number of cores available
ncores <- detectCores(logical=TRUE)

# Set up parallel environment
cl <- makeCluster(ncores, methods=FALSE)

# Export objects to parallel environment
clusterSetRNGStream(cl,1234567) # not necessary since we do not sample
clusterExport(cl, c("kfunctions","frq","dvec","case","control","polygon", "MonteCarloKfun", "khat", 
                    "as.points", "secal"))

# For 1 parameter use parSapply
outpar <- parSapply(cl,i,runpar)

# close parallel environment
stopCluster(cl)
```

Does anyone know if there is a possibility to add a progress bar to the parSapply function. Ideally I would like something similar to pbapply of the pbapply library.

Comment: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/surveillance/html/plapply.html

Comment: See the [`parabar`](https://parabar.mihaiconstantin.com/) package. It is *vaguely* based on my answer below. Disclaimer: I am the author of the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parSapply` function doesn't support a progress bar, and I don't think there is any really good way to implement one by adding extra code to the task function, although people have made valiant efforts to do that.

The `doSNOW` package supports progress bars, so you could either use that directly or write a wrapper function that works like the `parSapply` function. Here's one way to write such a wrapper function:

```
# This function is similar to "parSapply", but doesn't preschedule
# tasks and doesn't support "simplify" and "USE.NAMES" options
pbSapply <- function(cl, X, FUN, ...) {
  registerDoSNOW(cl)
  pb <- txtProgressBar(max=length(X))
  on.exit(close(pb))
  progress <- function(n) setTxtProgressBar(pb, n)
  opts <- list(progress=progress)
  foreach(i=X, .combine='c', .options.snow=opts) %dopar% {
    FUN(i, ...)
  }
}
```

You can easily modify this function to use either the `tkProgressBar` or `winProgressBar` function.

Here's an example use of `pbSapply`:

```
library(doSNOW)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(3)
x <- pbSapply(cl, 1:100, function(i, j) {Sys.sleep(1); i + j}, 100)
```

Note that this doesn't use prescheduling, so the performance won't be as good as `parSapply` if you have small tasks.

Answer (score 2):

**Update - Feb 20, 2023**

You can achieve this using the [`parabar`](https://parabar.mihaiconstantin.com/) package. Disclaimer: I am the author of the package.

You can use the package in an interactive `R` session as follows.

```r
# Load the package.
library(parabar)

# Define a task to run in parallel.
task <- function(x) {
    # Sleep a bit.
    Sys.sleep(0.01)

    # Return the result of a computation.
    return(x + 1)
}

# Start a backend that supports progress tracking (i.e., `async`).
backend <- start_backend(cores = 4, cluster_type = "psock", backend_type = "async")

# Configure the bar if necessary, or change the bar engine.
configure_bar(
    format = " > completed :current out of :total tasks [:percent] [:elapsed]"
)

# Run the task.
results <- par_sapply(backend, 1:1000, task)

# Update the progress bar options.
configure_bar(
    format = "[:bar] :percent"
)

# Run the task again.
results <- par_sapply(backend, 1:1000, task)

# Stop the backend.
stop_backend(backend)
```

If you need more flexibility (e.g., when building an `R` package). There is
also a lower-level API based on `R6` classes.

```r
# Create a specification object.
specification <- Specification$new()

# Set the number of cores.
specification$set_cores(cores = 4)

# Set the cluster type.
specification$set_type(type = "psock")

# Create a progress tracking context.
context <- ProgressDecorator$new()

# Get a backend that supports progress-tracking.
backend <- AsyncBackend$new()

# Register the backend with the context.
context$set_backend(backend)

# Start the backend.
context$start(specification)

# Get a modern bar instance.
bar <- ModernBar$new()

# Register the bar with the context.
context$set_bar(bar)

# Configure the bar.
context$configure_bar(
    show_after = 0,
    format = " > completed :current out of :total tasks [:percent] [:elapsed]"
)

# Run a task in parallel (i.e., approx. 3.125 seconds).
context$sapply(x = 1:1000, fun = task)

# Get the task output.
output <- backend$get_output()

# Close the backend.
context$stop()
```

---

Here is a proposed workflow, which perhaps fits [Steve Weston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2109128/steve-weston)'s characterization
as a *valiant effort*. Yet, with some overhead, it accomplishes what I am
primarily interested in, i.e., (1) a cross-platform solution, (2) not tempering
with low-level `parallel` implementation details, and (3) being parsimonious
concerning the dependencies used.

In a nutshell, the code below does the following:

- The function `prepare_file_for_logging` creates a temporary file (i.e.,
  `OS`-specific location) that will be used later on to report and track the
  progress of the parallel task execution.
- The function `par_sapply_with_progress` starts an `R` session in the
  background (i.e., without blocking the main session).

  - In this background session, it sets up a cluster (i.e., it can be either
    `PSOCK` or `FORK`) and runs the task in parallel via the function
    `parallel::parSapply`.
  - During each task run, the workers (i.e., cluster nodes) report the
    progress to the temporary file (i.e., strictly in the form of a new line
    to avoid race conditions).
- Back in the main process, the function `track_progress` monitors the temporary
  file and displays and updates a progress bar based on its contents.

  - The main process remains blocked until the progress bar is completed and
    the background process has been terminated.

The libraries used are `parallel` and `callr`, and some other functions from
`base` and `utils`. For the sake of clarity, the code below is explicitly
commented.

### Usage

```r
# Load libraries.
library(parallel)
library(callr)

# How many times to run?
runs <- 40

# Prepare file for logging the progress.
file_name <- prepare_file_for_logging()

# Run the task in parallel without blocking the main process.
process <- par_sapply_with_progress(
    # Cluster specifications.
    cores = 4,
    type = "PSOCK",

    # Where to write the progress.
    file_name = file_name,

    # Task specifications (i.e., just like in `parallel::parSapply`).
    x = 1:runs,
    fun = function(x, y) {
        # Wait a little.
        Sys.sleep(0.5)

        # Do something useful.
        return(x * y)
    },
    args = list(
        y = 10
    )
)

# Monitor the progress (i.e., blocking the main process until completion).
track_progress(
    process = process,
    iterations = runs,
    file_name = file_name,
    cleanup = TRUE
)

# Show the results.
print(process$get_result())

# |=====================================================================| 100%
#  [1]  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180
# [19] 190 200 210 220 230 240 250 260 270 280 290 300 310 320 330 340 350 360
# [37] 370 380 390 400
```

### Implementation

#### The function for preparing a temporary file

```r
# Create and get temporary file name.
prepare_file_for_logging <- function(file_name) {
    # If the file name is missing.
    if(missing(file_name)) {
        # Get a temporary file name (i.e., OS specific).
        file_name <- tempfile()
    }

    # Create the actual file to avoid race conditions.
    file_created <- file.create(file_name)

    # Indicate if something went wrong creating the file.
    stopifnot("Failed to create file." = file_created)

    return(file_name)
}
```

#### The function for running the task in parallel

```r
# Run task in parallel and log the progress.
par_sapply_with_progress <- function(cores, type, file_name, x, fun, args) {
    # Decorate the task function to enable progress tracking.
    get_decorated_task <- function(task) {
        # Evaluate symbol.
        force(task)

        # Create wrapper.
        return(function(x, file_name, ...) {
            # Update the progress on exit.
            on.exit({
                # Write processed element to file.
                cat("\n", file = file_name, append = TRUE)
            })

            return(task(x, ...))
        })
    }

    # Get the decorated task.
    fun_decorated <- get_decorated_task(fun)

    # Start a background process.
    background_process <- callr::r_bg(function(cores, type, file_name, x, fun_decorated, args) {
        # Make cluster.
        cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(cores, type = type)

        # Close the cluster on exit.
        on.exit({
            # Stop the cluster.
            parallel::stopCluster(cluster)
        })

        # Output.
        output <- do.call(parallel::parSapply, c(
            list(cluster, x, fun_decorated, file_name), args
        ))

        # Return the results to the background process.
        return(output)
    }, args = list(cores, type, file_name, x, fun_decorated, args))

    # Return the background process `R6` object.
    return(background_process)
}
```

#### The function for tracking the progress

```r
# Track progress and keep the main process busy.
track_progress <- function(process, iterations, file_name, cleanup = TRUE) {
    if (cleanup) {
        on.exit({
            # Remove the file (i.e., just in case).
            unlink(file_name)
       })
    }

    # Create a progress bar.
    bar <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = iterations, initial = NA, style = 3)

    # Record the number of processed iterations (i.e., runs).
    n_tasks_processed <- 0

    # While the process is alive.
    while(n_tasks_processed < iterations) {
        # Get the number of tasks processed.
        n_tasks_processed <- length(scan(file_name, blank.lines.skip = FALSE, quiet = TRUE))

        # If the process that started the workers is finished.
        if(!process$is_alive()) {
            # Indicate that all tasks have been processed.
            n_tasks_processed <- iterations
        }

        # Update the progress bar.
        setTxtProgressBar(bar, n_tasks_processed)
    }

    # Close the progress bar.
    close(bar)

    # Wait for the process to close.
    process$wait()
}
```

### Things to consider

Concerning logging and reading the progress from the temporary file, there are
two things I can think of for reducing the overhead:

- First, one can consider reducing the granularity of the reporting (i.e.,
  perhaps it is not necessary to log the progress after each task run, but, say,
  every fifth or so).
- Second, one may also consider reducing the update frequency of the progress
  bar. Currently, the `track_progress` continuously scans the temporary file and
  updates the progress bar. However, this is likely not necessary. Perhaps a
  better way is to set a timeout between subsequent file scans and progress bar
  updates.

Finally, I personally prefer opening a cluster once and reusing it across
different parts of my code. In this scenario, I would switch from `callr::r_bg`
(i.e., short-lived background `R` process) to  `callr::r_session` (i.e.,
permanent `R` session) for more control (i.e., also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73962109/5252007)).

I hope this helps others that have struggled with this issue as well.