# How to show progressbar in doParallel?

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

doSNOW can show progressbar like below

[How to show the progress of code in parallel computation in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684721/how-to-show-the-progress-of-code-in-parallel-computation-in-r)

is there a way to get progressbar in doParallel?

---

Update:

below is a minimal reproducible example

```
library(foreach)

library(doParallel)

mc <- detectCores()

cl <- makeCluster(mc)

registerDoParallel(cl)

result <- foreach(i = 1:100) %dopar% {
  rnorm(1000000) %>% sd
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: You could make a nice question out of it if you'd provide a [mcve].

Comment: Historically it has been shown that because `doParallel` does its "combine" all at the end, it is unlikely to be able to get good progress. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10982524. It is possible that things have changed since that answer, I'm not aware.