# How to minimize the unacceptably long run time of the created R code

Tags: r, for-loop, runtime, missing-data, large-data

There is a code with three for loops running with data containing enough missing values. The major problem is with the **unacceptably long run time which seems to take at least more than a month** although I try to keep my PC opened during most of the day.

The structure below is 100% correct from what I am trying to achieve when I test with a very few data points. But as the number of columns and rows become 2781 and 280, respectively, I perceive it takes forever although I am 100% sure that this is running correctly even when I see the updated environment window of my R-Studio each time I refresh it.

My data also has lots of missing values, probably 40% or something. I think this is making the computation time extremely longer as well.

The data dimension is 315 * 2781.
However, I am trying to achieve an output in a 280 * 2781 matrix form.

May I please get help minimizing the run time of this following code?
It would be very appreciated if I can!

```
options(java.parameters = "- Xmx8000m")
memory.limit(size=8e+6)

data=read.table("C:/Data/input.txt",T,sep="\t");
data=data.frame(data)[,-1]



corr<-NULL
corr2<-NULL
corr3<-NULL


for(i in 1:280) 
{
  corr2<-NULL
  for(j in 1:2781)
  {
    data2<-data[,-j]
    corr<-NULL
    for(k in 1:2780)
    {
      ifelse((is.error(grangertest(data[i:(i+35),j] ~ data2[i:(i+35),k], order = 1, na.action = na.omit)$P[2])==TRUE) || (grangertest(data[i:(i+35),j] ~ data2[i:(i+35),k], order = 1, na.action = na.omit)$P[2])>0.05|| (is.na(grangertest(data[i:(i+35),j] ~ data2[i:(i+35),k], order = 1, na.action = na.omit)$P[2])==TRUE),corr<-cbind(corr,0),corr<-cbind(corr,1))
    }
    corr2<-rbind(corr2,corr)
  }
  corr3<-rbind(corr3,rowSums(corr2))
}
```

The snippet of my data is as below:

```
> dput(data[1:30, 1:10])
structure(c(0.567388170165941, 0.193093325709924, 0.965938209090382, 
0.348295788047835, 0.496113050729036, 0.0645384560339153, 0.946750836912543, 
0.642093246569857, 0.565092500532046, 0.0952424583956599, 0.444063827162609, 
0.709971546428278, 0.756330407923087, 0.601746253203601, 0.341865634545684, 
0.953319212188944, 0.0788604547269642, 0.990508111426607, 0.35519331949763, 
0.697004508692771, 0.285368352662772, 0.274287624517456, 0.575733694015071, 
0.12937490013428, 0.00476219342090189, 0.684308280004188, 0.189448777819052, 
0.615732178557664, 0.404873769031838, 0.357331350911409, 0.565436001634225, 
0.380773033713922, 0.348490287549794, 0.0473814208526164, 0.389312234241515, 
0.562123290728778, 0.30642102798447, 0.911173274740577, 0.566258994862437, 
0.837928073247895, 0.107747194357216, 0.253737836843356, 0.651503744535148, 
0.187739939894527, 0.951192815322429, 0.740037888288498, 0.0817571650259197, 
0.740519099170342, 0.601534485351294, 0.120900869136676, 0.415282893227413, 
0.591146623482928, 0.698511375114322, 0.08557975362055, 0.139396222075447, 
0.303953414550051, 0.0743798329494894, 0.0293272000271827, 0.335832208395004, 
0.665010208031163, 0.0319741254206747, 0.678886031731963, 0.154593498911709, 
0.275712370406836, 0.828485634410754, 0.921500099124387, 0.651940459152684, 
0.00574865937232971, 0.82236105017364, 0.55089360428974, 0.209424041677266, 
0.861786168068647, 0.672873278381303, 0.301034058211371, 0.180336013436317, 
0.481560358777642, 0.901354183442891, 0.986482679378241, 0.90117057505995, 
0.476308439625427, 0.638073122361675, 0.27481731469743, 0.689271076582372, 
0.324349449947476, 0.56620552809909, 0.867861548438668, 0.78374840435572, 
0.0668482843320817, 0.276675389613956, 0.990600393852219, 0.990227151894942, 
0.417612489778548, 0.391012848122045, 0.348758921027184, 0.0799746725242585, 
0.88941288786009, 0.511429069796577, 0.0338982092216611, 0.240115304477513, 
0.0268365524243563, 0.67206134647131, 0.816803207853809, 0.344421110814437, 
0.864659120794386, 0.84128700569272, 0.116056860191748, 0.303730394458398, 
0.48192183743231, 0.341675494797528, 0.0622653553728014, 0.823110743425786, 
0.483212807681412, 0.968748248415068, 0.953057422768325, 0.116025703493506, 
0.327919023809955, 0.590675016632304, 0.832283023977652, 0.342327545629814, 
0.576901035616174, 0.942689201096073, 0.59300709143281, 0.565881528891623, 
0.600007816683501, 0.133237989619374, 0.873827134957537, 0.744597729761153, 
0.755133397178724, 0.0245723063126206, 0.97799762734212, 0.636845340020955, 
0.73828601022251, 0.644093665992841, 0.57204390084371, 0.496023115236312, 
0.703613247489557, 0.149237307952717, 0.0871439634356648, 0.0632112647872418, 
0.83703236351721, 0.433215840253979, 0.430483993608505, 0.924051651498303, 
0.913056606892496, 0.914889572421089, 0.215407102368772, 0.76880722376518, 
0.269207723205909, 0.865548757137731, 0.28798541566357, 0.391722843516618, 
0.649806497385725, 0.459413924254477, 0.907465039752424, 0.48731207777746, 
0.554472463205457, 0.779784266138449, 0.566323830280453, 0.208658932242543, 
0.958056638715789, 0.61858483706601, 0.838681482244283, 0.286310768220574, 
0.895410191034898, 0.448722236789763, 0.297688684659079, 0.33291415637359, 
0.0115265529602766, 0.850776052568108, 0.764857453294098, 0.469730701530352, 
0.222089925780892, 0.0496484278701246, 0.32886885642074, 0.356443469878286, 
0.612877089297399, 0.727906176587567, 0.0292073413729668, 0.429160050582141, 
0.232313714455813, 0.678631312213838, 0.642334033036605, 0.99107678886503, 
0.542449960019439, 0.835914565017447, 0.52798323193565, 0.303808332188055, 
0.919654499506578, 0.944237019168213, 0.52141259261407, 0.794379767496139, 
0.72268659202382, 0.114752230467275, 0.175116094760597, 0.437696389388293, 
0.852590200025588, 0.511136321350932, 0.30879021063447, 0.174206420546398, 
0.14262041519396, 0.375411552377045, 0.0204910831525922, 0.852757754037157, 
0.631567053496838, 0.475924106314778, 0.508682047016919, 0.307679089019075, 
0.70284536993131, 0.851252349093556, 0.0868967010173947, 0.586291917832568, 
0.0529140203725547, 0.440692059928551, 0.207642213441432, 0.777513341512531, 
0.141496006632224, 0.548626560717821, 0.419565241318196, 0.0702310993801802, 
0.499403427587822, 0.189343606121838, 0.370725362794474, 0.888076487928629, 
0.83070912421681, 0.466137421084568, 0.177098380634561, 0.91202046489343, 
0.142300580162555, 0.823691181838512, 0.41561916610226, 0.939948018174618, 
0.806491429451853, 0.795849160756916, 0.566376683535054, 0.36814984655939, 
0.307756055146456, 0.602875682059675, 0.506007500691339, 0.538658684119582, 
0.420845189364627, 0.663071365095675, 0.958144341595471, 0.793743418296799, 
0.983086514985189, 0.266262857476249, 0.817585011478513, 0.122843299992383, 
0.989197303075343, 0.71584410732612, 0.500571243464947, 0.397394519997761, 
0.659465527161956, 0.459530522814021, 0.602246116613969, 0.250076721422374, 
0.17533828667365, 0.6599256307818, 0.184704560553655, 0.15679649473168, 
0.513444944983348, 0.205572377191857, 0.430164282443002, 0.131548407254741, 
0.914019819349051, 0.935795902274549, 0.857401241315529, 0.977940042736009, 
0.41389597626403, 0.179183913161978, 0.431347143370658, 0.477178965462372, 
0.121315707685426, 0.107695729471743, 0.634954946814105, 0.859707030234858, 
0.855825762730092, 0.708672808250412, 0.674073817208409, 0.672288877889514, 
0.622144045541063, 0.433355041313916, 0.952878215815872, 0.229569894727319, 
0.289388840552419, 0.937473804224283, 0.116283216979355, 0.659604362910613, 
0.240837284363806, 0.726138337515295, 0.68390148691833, 0.381577257299796, 
0.899390475358814, 0.26472729514353, 0.0383855854161084, 0.855232689995319, 
0.655799814499915, 0.335587574867532, 0.163842789363116, 0.0353666560258716, 
0.048316186061129), .Dim = c(30L, 10L))
```

Comment: It would be great to comment the code along the way to make sure we understand what it is supposed to do. As a general suggestion in R:
- `c`, `rbind`, `cbind` to rewrite vectors are very computationally expensive, the best would be to create an output vector with the expected number of elements, then overwrite it in each single position with the output of the for cycle. 
- for cycles in R are very slow, I suggest you exploit `apply`/`sapply`/`lapply` syntaxes
- deleting one row at a time (`data[,-j]`) might also be quite heavy
- deleting one column at a time is also

Comment: If your machine has several cores, then you can parallelize your code, @Eric. See: [Parallelized loops with R](https://www.blasbenito.com/post/02_parallelizing_loops_with_r/)

Comment: Won't `data[i:(i+35),j]` error once `i` gets to `246`?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data[1:30, 1:10])`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas: Please check my dput above.

Comment: @jblood94: Thank you for pointing it out. I should have clarified about the original data dimension which I put as 315 * 2781.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted just the inner loop to `mapply` and did a quick speed test:

```
library(lmtest)

data <- matrix(runif(315*2781), nrow = 315)

get01 <- function(x, y) {
  try(gt <- grangertest(x ~ y, order = 1, na.action = na.omit)$P[2])
  exists("gt") && gt < 0.05 && !is.na(gt)
}

i <- 1; j <- 1
system.time(corr <- mapply(function(k) {get01(data[i:(i+35),j], data[i:(i+35),k])}, (1:2781)[-j]))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   13.13    0.25   13.38
```

It would need to perform that `mapply` 778400 times, so that puts it at about 120 days. You'll either need a different approach with the Granger test or several cores. Here's the command to replace the full loop:

```
corr3 <- t(mapply(function(i) colSums(mapply(function(j) mapply(function(k) {get01(data[i:(i+35),j], data[i:(i+35),k])}, (1:2781)[-j]), 1:2781)), 1:280))
```

Replace that first `mapply` with `simplify2array(parLapply` to parallelize:

```
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
clusterExport(cl, list("data", "get01"))
parLapply(cl, cl, function(x) require(lmtest))
corr3 <- t(simplify2array(parLapply(cl, 1:280, function(i) colSums(mapply(function(j) mapply(function(k) {get01(data[i:(i+35),j], data[i:(i+35),k])}, (1:2781)[-j]), 1:2781)))))
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Firstly I get the two error messages at this moment where the reason behind first error seems a bit confusing given the code structure at this moment. I would really appreciate if these could be kindly considered please. Many thanks. (1) Error in rval[i, j, drop = drop., ...] : subscript out of bounds (2) Error in mcmapply(function(i) colSums(mapply(function(j) mapply(function(k) { : 
  'mc.cores' > 1 is not supported on Windows

Comment: Besides, my data number of row is actually 315 but I am estimating in a rolling window manner with the previous 36 data points including the current. Hope this clarifies further.

Comment: I am trying to achieve an output in a 280 * 2781 matrix form.

Comment: I tried using your second code which does not uses mcmapply with very few unit of data to see how it works. Then I tried to get the output even ignoring the following error message "(1) Error in rval[i, j, drop = drop., ...] : subscript out of bounds". Then the output still seems to be valid. The code I tested from yours is this: (1) Error in rval[i, j, drop = drop., ...] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: I'll transition to a Windows machine and work out the parLappply. It may take a while to get to it, though. Thanks for the clarification on the row size.

Comment: Thank you so much again. So basically the data row is 315 but I am always using the previous 36 rows including the current row to run granger causality test each time in a rolling window manner with one cell against all other cells all belonging to the same row as a counting manner. This is why the code looks like this and the total run of row is 280 instead.

Comment: I find the following blog but they also mention your method parLapply(). https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/07/implementing-mclapply-on-windows-a-primer-on-embarrassingly-parallel-computation-on-multicore-systems-with-r/

Comment: `parLapply` is not that difficult to use. I've got my Windows machine up, and I'm testing the code.

Comment: Thank you. I think this blog's hacking style may not be 100% credible enough yet as the author's suggested weblink leading to his code isn't working anymore. Intuitively, 
their solution is pretty long so I think this itself could consume enough memory and time which won't be practical for my case. Therefore, I do agree with you that the parLapply() itself would be the solution. Probably we could simply focus on the parLapply() solution itself.

Comment: Just curious--how many cores do you have (from `detectCores()`)?

Comment: I think the other person's code is below.

Comment: I've updated the post with `parLapply`. If Rui's `granger_test` works for you, using that with what I have above will probably be close to the best solution without a complete overhaul of `lmtest::grangertest` and `lmtest::waldtest` that will allow you to vectorize over your matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried running the part "parLapply(cl, function(x) require(lmtest))" which gave me an error saying "Error in x[i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable". Maybe I am missing some syntax here. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry just saw it updated now.

Comment: Just updated it, should have been `parLapply(cl, cl, function(x) require(lmtest))`

Comment: Thank you again. I see the function (i)'s row count of 280 is missing but seems to recognize 1:4 as rows if I am correct. The answer seems to be different as a result unfortunately.

Comment: The 4 was left over from testing. I updated it to 280.

Comment: Thank you so much for your confirmation!

Comment: I agree that this is the faster or fastest method than what I used to use. But since my data have many missing values this code is still running now for more than two weeks, still less than what I would expect for my previous trial. But this time the problem is, I cannot know how much this code has run and how much left as it is still running. The problem is, I cannot run more codes here as this current code is still running now. Is there an easy way to know my progress in this situation?

Comment: I'm almost certain you can't check the progress of an already-running `parLapply`. In similar situations, I've had the function inside the `parLapply` save the results in a separate file (whose name would include the iterator `i`). The nice thing about that solution is that if the process is interrupted, you can pick up where you left off by changing `1:280` to the indices remaining to be processed. Otherwise, there are progress bar solutions (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51141332/9463489). But for either, you would need to restart the process. Just curious--how many cores are going?

Comment: When I run your last code using simplify2array, I cannot see how many cores are being used. Is there a way to see them?

Comment: It's the length of the `cl` object. If you're in RStudio, it will say, e.g., "List of 8" in the environment pane.

Comment: Yes I see list of 8.

Comment: So if it's been running for 2 weeks, you're maybe halfway done.

Comment: Thank you. But what does this list of 8 mean? How did you calculate the remaining time based on this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239546/discussion-between-jblood94-and-eric).

Comment: Hello again. If I don't want to derive the column sum but only want to derive the granger cause direction and show whether those are significant at the 5% level, how do I modify this code? For instance, if "j" granger causes "k" at the 5% significance level at point "i", I want to derive like "cbind(i,j,k,1)" if significant and "cbind(i,j,k,0)" if not then rbind these all showing 4 columns with a long row.

Comment: Hello again. If I don't want to derive the column sum but only want to derive the granger cause direction and show whether those are significant at the 5% level, how do I modify this code? For instance, if "j" granger causes "k" at the 5% significance level at point "i", I want to derive like "cbind(i,j,k,1)" if significant and "cbind(i,j,k,0)" if not then rbind these all showing 4 columns with a long row.

Comment: I would change it to `corr3 <- array(unlist(parLapply(cl, 1:280, function(i) mapply(function(j) mapply(function(k) {get01(data[i:(i+35),j], data[i:(i+35),k])}, (1:2781)[-j]), 1:2781))), c(2780, 2781, 280))`. Then `corr3[k,j,i] == 1` would correspond to "j" granger causes "k" at the 5% significance level at point "i".

Comment: If you need to reshape, check out `aperm`.

Comment: Thanks. This function does not seem to be easy at a glance. For instance, what does it mean by "aperm(x, c(2,1,3))" ? I can see x in the example, but I don't know how c(2,1,3) plays here even from the output I see

Comment: If you want it to be `corr3[i,j,k]` instead, it would be `aperm(corr3, 3:1)`.

Comment: Thanks. But what I actually want is to have like rbind((i,j,k,1), (i,j,k,0), (i,j,k,1)...) where the fourth element is one or zero depending on the granger causality.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, as it will be memory inefficient, but for that, use `arrayInd`, like: `cbind(arrayInd(seq_along(corr3), dim(corr3)), c(corr3))[,c(3:1, 4)]`. First, I would recommend changing `get01` to return `integer` or `boolean` values since they will take less memory (I updated my answer to show an example--it actually runs slightly faster, too). Or, if you already have `corr3` as `numeric`, do `mode(corr3) <- "integer"`.

Comment: That worked quite well. Thank you! Now I got 83072178 rows to export to excel which is really huge. Do you have a suggested way for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version, not parallelized, that speeds up the code in the question by a factor greater than 4.

Some bottlenecks in the question's code are easy to detect:

- The matrices `corr?` are extended inside the loops. The solution is to reserve memory beforehand;
- The test `grangertest` is called 3 times per inner iteration when only one is needed;
- To `cbind` with `0` or `1` is in fact creating a vector, not a matrix.

Here is a comparative test between the question's code and the function below.

```
library(lmtest)

# avoids loading an extra package
is.error <- function(x){
  inherits(x, c("error", "try-error"))
}

Lag <- 5L
nr <- nrow(data)
nc <- ncol(data)

t0 <- system.time({
  corr<-NULL
  corr2<-NULL
  corr3<-NULL
  for(i in 1:(nr - Lag))
  {
    corr2<-NULL
    data3 <- data[i:(i + Lag), ]
    for(j in 1:nc)
    {
      data2<-data[,-j]
      corr<-NULL
      for(k in 1:(nc - 1L))
      {
        ifelse((is.error(grangertest(data[i:(i+Lag),j] ~ data2[i:(i+Lag),k], order = 1, na.action = na.omit)$P[2])==TRUE) ||
                 (grangertest(data[i:(i+Lag),j] ~ data2[i:(i+Lag),k], order = 1, na.action = na.omit)$P[2])>0.05 ||
                 (is.na(grangertest(data[i:(i+Lag),j] ~ data2[i:(i+Lag),k], order = 1, na.action = na.omit)$P[2])==TRUE),
               corr<-cbind(corr,0),
               corr<-cbind(corr,1)
        )
      }
      corr2 <- rbind(corr2, corr)
    }
    corr3<-rbind(corr3, rowSums(corr2))
  }
  corr3
})
```

---

I will use a simplified version of `lmtest::grangertest`.

```
granger_test <- function (x, y, order = 1, na.action = na.omit, ...) {
  xnam <- deparse(substitute(x))
  ynam <- deparse(substitute(y))
  n <- length(x)
  all <- cbind(x = x[-1], y = y[-1], x_1 = x[-n], y_1 = y[-n])
  y <- as.vector(all[, 2])
  lagX <- as.matrix(all[, (1:order + 2)])
  lagY <- as.matrix(all[, (1:order + 2 + order)])
  fm <- lm(y ~ lagY + lagX)
  rval <- lmtest::waldtest(fm, 2, ...)
  attr(rval, "heading") <- c("Granger causality test\n", paste("Model 1: ", 
                                                               ynam, " ~ ", "Lags(", ynam, ", 1:", order, ") + Lags(", 
                                                               xnam, ", 1:", order, ")\nModel 2: ", ynam, " ~ ", "Lags(", 
                                                               ynam, ", 1:", order, ")", sep = ""))
  rval
}
```

And now the function to run the tests.

```
f_Rui <- function(data, Lag){
  nr <- nrow(data)
  nc <- ncol(data)
  corr3 <- matrix(0, nrow = nr - Lag, ncol = nc)
  data3 <- matrix(0, nrow = Lag + 1L, ncol = nc)
  data2 <- matrix(0, nrow = Lag + 1L, ncol = nc - 1L)
  for(i in 1:(nr - Lag)) {
    corr2 <- matrix(0, nrow = nc, ncol = nc - 1L)
    data3[] <- data[i:(i + Lag), ]
    for(j in 1:nc) {
      corr <- integer(nc - 1L)
      data2[] <- data3[, -j]
      for(k in 1:(nc - 1L)){
        res <- tryCatch(
          grangertest(x = data2[, k], y = data3[, j], order = 1, na.action = na.omit),
          error = function(e) e
        )
        if(!inherits(res, "error") && !is.na(res[['Pr(>F)']][2]) && res[['Pr(>F)']][2] <= 0.05) {
          corr[k] <- 1L
        }
      }
      corr2[j, ] <- corr
    }
    corr3[i, ] <- rowSums(corr2)
  }
  corr3
}
```

The results are `identical` and the timings much better.

```
t1 <- system.time({
  res <- f_Rui(data, 5L)
})

identical(corr3, res)
#[1] TRUE

times <- rbind(t0, t1)
t(t(times)/t1)
#   user.self sys.self  elapsed user.child sys.child
#t0  4.682908 1.736111 4.707783        NaN       NaN
#t1  1.000000 1.000000 1.000000        NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Barrads: Thank you but I think I the "f_Rui(data, 5L)" in the final step is not executable for my case unfortunately. It says "Error in f_Rui(data, 5L) : unused argument (5)" Also, could you please explain what 5L is and why it is given? Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry I see that the lag is something that I set up as the rolling window as I did like 35.

Comment: Thank you! It was a good opportunity to learn!