# R doParallel Progress bar to monitor finished jobs

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to write a CRAN package with multithreaded capabilities. I achieved a perfect solution with `doSNOW`, but the package has been flagged as "superseded" by the CRAN team and they asked me to switch to a `doParallel` solution. This is fine, however I could not find a way to monitor the number of jobs completed using `doParallel` in the same way I did with `doSNOW`. Here is my `doSNOW` solution:

```
# Set up parameters
nthreads<-2
nreps<-100
funrep<-function(i){
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    res<-c(log2(i),log10(i))
    return(res)
}
# doSNOW solution
library(doSNOW)
cl<-makeCluster(nthreads)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
pb<-txtProgressBar(0,nreps,style=3)
progress<-function(n){
    setTxtProgressBar(pb,n)
}
opts<-list(progress=progress)
i<-0
output<-foreach(i=icount(nreps),.combine=c,.options.snow=opts) %dopar% {
    s<-funrep(i)
    return(s)
}
close(pb)
stopCluster(cl)
```

And here's a doParallel solution as suggested [in a previous Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423760/how-do-you-create-a-progress-bar-when-using-the-foreach-function-in-r/10982524#10982524). However, as you can see, it doesn't print progress as the jobs are done, it just does it when the results are combined, at the very end.

```
# doParallel solution
library(doParallel)
progcombine<-function(){
  count<-0
  function(...) {
    count<<-count+length(list(...))
    setTxtProgressBar(pb,count)
    utils::flush.console()
    c(...)
  }
}
cl <- makeCluster(nthreads)
registerDoParallel(cl)
output<-foreach(i = icount(nreps),.combine=progcombine()) %dopar% {
    funrep(i)
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Can you suggest me a solution to monitor job status completion using `doParallel` or at least without using the superseded `doSNOW`? Possibly with a progress bar and also possibly with multi-OS capability. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you consider [log4r](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/log4r/index.html) - can log both to file & console at the same time. Then log the done job so you can easily following the progress.

Comment: Have you looked at the `pbapply` package? I don't know a lot about this but it's my go to package for parallel + progress bar tasks.

Comment: Actually, when I run your code I see a progress bar incrementing at the completion of each task (more or less). Do you have the option `.multicombine = TRUE`? I do not, and it is not set to TRUE by default.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: I eventually settled for a *valiant*, but cross-platform solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73940644/5252007. Also, in my package, I am using a permanent session instead of a background process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find a solution with doParallel (I don't think it supports progress bars for job completion), but maybe you can try the new package **pbapply**:

```
# pbapply solution
library(pbapply)
cl<-parallel::makeCluster(nthreads)
invisible(parallel::clusterExport(cl=cl,varlist=c("nreps")))
invisible(parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl=cl,library(utils)))
result<-pblapply(cl=cl,
                 X=1:nreps,
                 FUN=funrep)
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 7):

(disclaim: I'm the author of the progressr package and the future framework)

The [progressr](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/progressr) package can achieve this when using [doFuture](https://cran.r-project.org/package=doFuture) as a parallel backend to [foreach](https://cran.r-project.org/package=foreach):

```
library(progressr) ## use progressr for procession updates
library(doFuture)  ## attaches also foreach and future
registerDoFuture() ## tell foreach to use futures
plan(multisession) ## parallelize over a local PSOCK cluster

xs <- 1:5

with_progress({
  p <- progressor(along = xs) ## create a 5-step progressor
  y <- foreach(x = xs) %dopar% {
    p()                       ## signal a progression update
    Sys.sleep(6.0-x)
    sqrt(x)
  }
})
```

The default is to use `utils::txtProgressBar()` for progression reporting, but you can change this.  For example, the following will make progression updates being reported via `progress::progress_bar()` and `beepr::beep()`:

```r
progressr::handlers("progress", "beepr")
```

You can also add messages for each progression update, e.g.

```r
p(sprintf("x=%g", x))
```

FYI, `plan(multisession, workers = 2)` is short for `plan(cluster, workers = cl)` where `cl` is basically `cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2L)`.

PS. The objective of the progressr package is to provide a minimal, sustainable, extendable, and unified API for progression updates.  This, while being invariant to what iterator framework is used.

PPS. The progressr API is under development; it might take a while before it has identified its true self.

Comment: Honestly: well done! For my package, I will switch to your progressr once it goes on CRAN or Bioconductor. I will switch to it immediately for testing :-)

Comment: Tried to fix this with edit but edit queue was full: progressr::handler does not exist (anymore?). progressr::handlers("progress", "beepr") seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thx. I've fixed the typo; it should be `handlers()` - `handler()` never existed.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `surveillance::plapply`. The handling of the progress bar is implemented in the function to be parallelized.

```
funrep2 <- function(i){
  i <<- i + 1
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
  res <- c(log2(i), log10(i))
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  return(res)
}
```

After exporting objects to the clusters the handling is similar to your `parallel` solution so far:

```
library(parallel)
pb <- txtProgressBar(max=nreps, style=3)
cl <- makeCluster(nthreads)
clusterExport(cl, c("pb", "funrep2"), envir=environment())
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(surveillance))
i <- 0
output <- surveillance::plapply(1:nreps, "funrep2")
stopCluster(cl)
close(pb)

# |=============================================================================...     |  85%
```