# Showing progress_bar with doParallel + foreach

Tags: r, foreach, progress-bar, doparallel

I am using the example code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423760/how-do-you-create-a-progress-bar-when-using-the-foreach-function-in-r) to show a `progress_bar` (from the `progress` package) with `doParallel` + `foreach`. Solutions there however make use of `doSNOW` (e.g. code by Dewey Brooke that I am using for testing), which is more outdated than `doParallel` and returns this NOTE when building a package with CRAN flags:

> Uses the superseded package: ‘doSNOW (>= 1.0.19)’

Change this does not seems that as straightforward as expected. If only `registerDoSNOW` is replaced by `registerDoParallel`, and `.options.snow` by `.options.doparallel` the code will run, but in the second case will not show any progress bar at all.

I think this might relate to the use of `.options.X`. This part of the code is very obscure to me, since `.options.snow` works indeed when using `doSNOW`, but there is no documentation of the `foreach` man page about the use of this argument. Therefore, it is not surprising that `.options.doparallel` does not work, since it was just a wild guess of mine.

Including the call to `pb$tick()` within the `foreach` loop will not work either, and will actually cause the result to be wrong. So I am really out of ideas on where should I include this in the code.

Where `.options.snow` comes from? where should go `pb$tick()`, how to show the `progress_bar` object using `doParallel` here?

I paste below the code (`doSNOW` replaced by `doParallel`) for convenience, but credit again the [original source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423760/how-do-you-create-a-progress-bar-when-using-the-foreach-function-in-r):

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)

numCores<-detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(numCores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# progress bar ------------------------------------------------------------
library(progress)

iterations <- 100                               # used for the foreach loop  

pb <- progress_bar$new(
  format = "letter = :letter [:bar] :elapsed | eta: :eta",
  total = iterations,    # 100 
  width = 60)

progress_letter <- rep(LETTERS[1:10], 10)  # token reported in progress bar

# allowing progress bar to be used in foreach -----------------------------
progress <- function(n){
  pb$tick(tokens = list(letter = progress_letter[n]))
} 

opts <- list(progress = progress)

# foreach loop ------------------------------------------------------------
library(foreach)

foreach(i = 1:iterations, .combine = rbind, .options.doparallel = opts) %dopar% {
  summary(rnorm(1e6))[3]
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Hello @elcortegano, did you ever resolve this problem?

Comment: Not, unfortunately. And have not yet found an alternative to `doSNOW` for this task.

Answer (score 3):

`doParallel` still uses the `.options.snow` argument for whatever reason. Found this little tidbit in the [doParallel documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/doParallel.pdf).

> The doParallel backend supports both multicore and snow options passed through the foreach function. The supported multicore options are 1st `preschedule`, `set.seed`, `silent`, and `cores`, which are analogous to the similarly named arguments to `mclapply`, and are passed using the `.options.multicore` argument to foreach. The supported snow options are `preschedule`, which like its multicore analog can be used to chunk the tasks so that each worker gets a prescheduled chunk of tasks, and `attachExportEnv`, which can be used to attach the export environment in certain cases where R’s lexical scoping is unable to find a needed export. The snow options are passed to foreach using the `.options.snow` argument.

`foreach` is powerful package but whoever is maintaining it makes odd decisions.

---

## EDIT

`doParallel` does not support the `progress` multicore option. Therefore, a progress bar **will NOT display** if `registerDoParallel` is used instead of `registerDoSNOW`.

While `doSNOW` has been superseded, it's unclear if one is more outdated than the other since both have undergone very few changes, either than updating the current Maintainer ([doParallel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/NEWS) | [doSNOW](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doSNOW/NEWS)).

### `doSNOW`

```
doSNOW:::doSNOW <- function (obj, expr, envir, data) 
{
  cl <- data
  preschedule <- FALSE
  attachExportEnv <- FALSE
  progressWrapper <- function(...) NULL   # <- CRITICAL DIFFERENCE
  if (!inherits(obj, "foreach")) 
    stop("obj must be a foreach object")
  it <- iter(obj)
  accumulator <- makeAccum(it)
  options <- obj$options$snow
  if (!is.null(options)) {
    nms <- names(options)
    recog <- nms %in% c("preschedule", "attachExportEnv", 
                        "progress")      # <- CRITICAL DIFFERENCE
    if (any(!recog)) 
      warning(sprintf("ignoring unrecognized snow option(s): %s", 
                      paste(nms[!recog], collapse = ", ")), call. = FALSE)
...
```

### `doParallel`

```
doParallel:::doParallelSNOW <- function (obj, expr, envir, data) 
{
  cl <- data
  preschedule <- FALSE
  attachExportEnv <- FALSE
  # MISSING: progressWrapper <- function(...) NULL
  if (!inherits(obj, "foreach")) 
    stop("obj must be a foreach object")
  it <- iter(obj)
  accumulator <- makeAccum(it)
  options <- obj$options$snow
  if (!is.null(options)) {
    nms <- names(options)
    recog <- nms %in% c("preschedule", "attachExportEnv" #MISSING , "progress")
    if (any(!recog)) 
      warning(sprintf("ignoring unrecognized snow option(s): %s", 
                      paste(nms[!recog], collapse = ", ")), call. = FALSE)
...
```

Comment: Almost a year later... Still couldn't figure out a way to go about this. I feel it should be possible given that `parallel` is based, among other things, on `snow`. Your answer seems to point at `foreach` for lacking something. Would you mind elaborating a bit? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Mihai I updated my answer on why it won't work.  Short answer./.. A progress bar will not display with `doParallel` as the backend no matter how hard you try. Just use `doSNOW`.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks for updating. I was curious about a general solution (i.e., cross-platform and without relaying the implementation details of these parallel backends), and I came with the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73940644/5252007. Perhaps you may find it interesting to check out.

Comment: @Mihai Thanks for the link!! I've seen similar solutions, yet I really wanted to exploit the flexibility of the `progress` package when I was looking for a solution. I'm irritated with the maintainers of the `foreach` package. After Microsoft acquired Revolution Analytics, development for all those packages came to a screeching halt. When I finally get free time, I might fork `doParallel` to add in the "progress" option. Would love collaboration if you're down. Won't be for awhile however.

Comment: Happy that you've checked it out. You can, by the way, use that approach with the `progress` package as well. I would love to collaborate on what you proposed! When the time is right, just reply here or get in touch via the link in my profile.

Comment: I eventually wrote a package to track progress for both `PSOCK` and `FORK` clusters. You can [find it here](https://parabar.mihaiconstantin.com/). I would love to hear your thoughts and/ or suggestions.

Comment: @Mihai Can you provide a example of foreach + doParalle?

Comment: @Mihai Excelent. Thank you for developing the parabar that helps with this struggling task.