# I want to print the current simulation number while running my code in r

Tags: r, parallel-processing, simulation, data-analysis

I am using mclapply(1:nsim, f, mc.cores=4) in rstudio for parallel computing in linux. the function f is a predefined function by me. The number nsim = 500 is the number of simulations, so it is taking a lot of time to run this line since my function involves modeling 100000 data points. Is there any way to see the current number of simulation my screen\console (which is showing when i run it in windows with mc.cores = 1 ).

If there is any solution please let me know, this will help me check whether the program is running or the system is crashed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984556/is-there-way-to-track-progress-on-a-mclapply

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there way to track progress on a mclapply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984556/is-there-way-to-track-progress-on-a-mclapply)