# progress bar not working in foreach setting

Tags: r, foreach, progress-bar, domc

I have the following `foreach` setting in Ubuntu system where I need to have a progress-bar to monitor the progress.

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=detectCores()-1)
total <- 9000
# create progress bar
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = total, style = 3)
respar <- foreach(i = 1:total, .combine = rbind)%dopar%{
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
  i**3
}
close(pb)
```

However, the above the implementation is not working but the output in `respar` is as expected. Could you please comment if there is something wrong with this approach?

Note: The question is to identify the error in this approach of creating the progress-bar. The other similar questions did not deal with this combination of background setup for progress-bar creation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a progress bar when using the "foreach()" function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423760/how-do-you-create-a-progress-bar-when-using-the-foreach-function-in-r)

Comment: The approach maybe same, Can you please point out why this snippet is not working? I am looking to know what is hindering the showing of progress bar while execution, but not the code for creating a progress bar.

Comment: Your progress bar probably show up, but in all the other parallel sessions, not the main one.