# How to create one progress bar for several foreach loops in R

Tags: r, foreach, progress-bar

I do have 3 foreach loops, when I have done all the loops I consider my task as finished.

How can I get one progress bar for all my loops? Suppose that my loops look like this: (I got the functions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423760/how-do-you-create-a-progress-bar-when-using-the-foreach-function-in-r) question)

```
## Parallelization set up
n.cores <- parallel::detectCores() - 1
my.cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(n.cores, type = "PSOCK")
registerDoSNOW(my.cluster)


Q = 100

pb <- progress_bar$new(
  format = "Simulation = :Simulation [:bar] :elapsed | Remaining: :eta ",
  total = (Q*3),    
  width = 60)
prog_sim <- 1:Q*3
progress <- function(n){
  pb$tick(tokens = list(Simulation = prog_sim[n]))
} 
opts <- list(progress = progress)



task_1 <- foreach(i = 1:Q, .combine = rbind, .options.snow = opts) %dopar% {
  summary(rnorm(1e6))[3]
}

task_2 <- foreach(i = 1:Q, .combine = rbind, .options.snow = opts) %dopar% {
  summary(rnorm(1e6))[3]
}

task_3 <- foreach(i = 1:Q, .combine = rbind, .options.snow = opts) %dopar% {
  summary(rnorm(1e6))[3]
}
```

But in the console, I get these two bars printed, and the last one disappears when finished.
[image]

How can I get **one** big progress bar for several foreach loops?

Thanks in advance