# How can I track the progress *within* each instance of parallelized loop?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, progress-bar

I am running several MCMC in parallel. How could I track the progress of each MCMC? I am not asking how to track the progress of parallel loop, i.e., when each MCMC finishes; rather, I want to know the progress of each MCMC which is nested in the parallel loop. Is there any way to set up multiple progress bars? Or would I need to save some file within the nested loops to monitor?

```
#not executed so not sure if actually reprex, but the concept is there
#computer is still running my other code :)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cl <- makeCluster(mc <- getOption("cl.cores", parallel::detectCores()))

registerDoParallel(cl)

reprex <- foreach(1:10) %dopar% { 
  for(ii in 1:100){
    #I want to track this loop's progress within each instance
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
  } 
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423760/how-do-you-create-a-progress-bar-when-using-the-foreach-function-in-r)?

Comment: @RuiBarradas nope, that would only track the outer loop iterated 1:10.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there's no general support for having multiple progress bars in R, at least not across multiple lines in the R console.

Other than that, [**futureverse**](https://www.futureverse.org/) with [**doFuture**](https://doFuture.futureverse.org/) and [**progressr**](https://progressr.futureverse.org/) can give you near-live progress updates.  Here's the gist:

```
library(foreach)
library(doFuture)
library(progressr)

## Report on progress automatically
handlers(global = TRUE)

## Parallelize on local machine
plan(multisession)

## See https://progressr.futureverse.org/#a-progressor-cannot-be-created-in-the-global-environment
## for why we use local() here
reprex <- local({
  p <- progressor(steps = 10 * 100)
  y <- foreach(hh = 1:10) %dofuture% { 
    for(ii in 1:100){
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
      ## Report on progress thus far with a custom message
      p(sprintf("(hh, ii) = (%d, %d)", hh, ii))
    } 
  }
  y
})

## Stop local cluster
plan(sequential)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code, it helped quite a lot.

One extra feature that I found is that by setting class =  "sticky" I get to print some values of the chain, and they remain in the console.

```
p(sprintf("precision %.*f, width '%*.3f'", 3, pi, 8, pi), class =  "sticky")
```